# Отличия циклов и генераторов списков

Tags: python, циклы, генераторы

Есть список вложенных словарей, в которые также вложены списки и словари.
Из него, с помощью индексов и циклов нужно сформировать новый список. И это довольно просто сделать циклом, но мне интересно разобраться в генераторах, коль скоро они являются одной из фишек Python.
Собственно вопрос в следующем, почему при проходе по списку стандартным циклом:

```
girls_drivers = []

for user in users:
    friends = user.get('friends', [])
    for friend in friends:
        if friend['sex'] == 'F' and friend.get('cars'):
            girls_drivers.append(friend['name'])
```

все работает нормально, но если я пытаюсь создать такой же список с помощью генератора - он начинает ругаться, что нужен индекс. И без индексов (там, где в коде "-1") не работает.

```
girls_drivers = [friend.get('friends')[-1].get('name') for friend in users
                 if 'friends' in friend and friend['friends'][-1]['sex'] == 'F' and 'cars' in friend['friends'][-1]]
```

Каким образом можно сделать из цикла выше генератор, чтобы он перебирал все элементы списка, а не только -1 элемент списка? И почему генератору нужны индексы элементов, а циклу нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не понял, зачем у вас там индексация `[-1]` вообще. Ваш стандартный цикл аналогичен следующему *списковому сокращению*:

```
girls_drivers = [friend['name'] for user in users for friend in user.get('friends', []) 
                 if friend['sex'] == 'F' and friend.get('cars')]
```

А если хотите *генератор*, то просто замените квадратные скобки `girls_drivers = [ ... ]` на круглые `girls_drivers = ( ... )` это и всё отличие в синтаксисе между *списочным сокращением* и *генератором*.

P.S. Рецепт написания *списочного сокращения* из *обычной формы записи кода*:

- сразу за открывающей скобкой `[` пишем аргумент функции `list.append` - ведь это именно то, что будет добавляться в список
- циклы `for` идут точно в том же порядке, что и в обычной записи, просто в одну строку и без `:`
- перед закрывающей скобкой `]` идёт `if`, отбирающий элементы для добавления в список

Comment: Большое спасибо! Вы не представляете сколько времени я потратил на то, чтобы в этом разобраться, а все оказывается было так просто!

Comment: @Евгений Я на всякий случай добавил дополнительное пояснение